# What is a safe to include in .gitignore when creating repository in IntelliJ

Tags: java, git, maven, github, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ with installed plugin .ignore which can automatically generate .gitignore file.
While generating .gitignore with that plugin a window pop-up with many possibilities to be selected as a "ignored". But there are many options.

[image]

I'm still learning how to use git, how to compose project structure, and it's still amazing for me while creating only couple classes and interfaces- suddenly a lot of files are generated by IntelliJ in repository which will be also pushed to GitHub.

Is there any "general pattern" what is it safe to be ignored? 
For example working in IntelliJ with Maven in java 1.8? 
Off course keeping repository still possible to run when someone else would pull it from GitHub.

My previous project which I've made with my mentor, we have generated .gitignore with the same plugin and now it contains a lot of ignored files but unfortunately I don't remember which libreries/frameworks we have choose in generator.
For me as a beginner it looks complicated:

```
 # Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
*.class
*.log
*.ctxt
.mtj.tmp/
*.jar
*.war
*.nar
*.ear
*.zip
*.tar.gz
*.rar
hs_err_pid*
target/
pom.xml.tag
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.versionsBackup
pom.xml.next
release.properties
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
buildNumber.properties
.mvn/timing.properties
.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf
.idea/**/contentModel.xml
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries
cmake-build-*/
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml
*.iws
out/
.idea_modules/
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml
.idea/replstate.xml
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties
.idea/httpRequests
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: Last time I've found out an answer what I was whinking about. 
It's more directed to beginners like me, for the rest it's obvious.
When you generate .gitignore with .ignore generator it's completely safe to select all frameworks/languages which you are using. For example if you use Java language, and select "Java" in search window it will be still 100% executable for the users who would get your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of languages, frameworks and tools you're using in your project. Note that you can always edit the `.gitignore` file to match any constraints that might arise later on in your project.

That's a [listing](https://github.com/github/gitignore) of a collection of `.gitignore` templates.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Template list of ignored files depends on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As a general practice, I use the following .gitignore contents for java based project.
It is an evolving file contents based upon the requirements. In case of python, ruby based projects, you have to add other contents. In this .gitignore file, I consider the project to be used by Intellij Idea and Eclipse IDEs. I have also included gradle and maven specific files to be ignored.

```
# Gradle
# ------
.gradle
/build

# IDEA
# ----
.idea
.idea/
.shelf
/*.iml
/*.ipr
/*.iws
/out

/out/*.*


# Eclipse
# -------
*.classpath
*.project
*.settings

/bin
.metadata/
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath
.recommenders

# Eclipse Core
.project

# JDT-specific (Eclipse Java Development Tools)
.classpath

# STS (Spring Tool Suite)
.springBeans

# Code Recommenders
.recommenders/

# Logs
# ----
/*.log

# Others
# ----
**/*.class
**/*.bin
**/*.build
**/*.out
build
build/
**/*.jar

# Maven specific

target/

#Skip all SVN related
.svn/
.svn/entries
.svn*
*/.svn/*

#Skip all CVS related
CVS/
/CVS/*
**/CVS/*
.cvsignore
*/.cvsignore
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please check AEIMehdi answer which answer directly for my question. I think it could be valuable also for you.

Comment: `.idea` directory should always be checked into VCS.